# Anyone managed to release an app on Play Store with SMS & Call Log permissions?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

I am trying to release an app that will go through your call history and identify business places you called so you can catalog them for later use and easy access.
For this to work, of course, the apps needs `READ_CALL_LOG` permission. After submitting it to Play Store it got rejected saying *Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app*. The only suitable category I found and declared is *Device automation*.

So by looking around I found that is very hard to release an app that requires sensitive permissions unless it's a default call or SMS handler. Is there anybody here that managed to do it and is willing to share some tips?

I have done the following to try to justify the need for the permission:

- Pretty much the sole purpose of the app is to read call history so it is it's core functionality.
- It's clearly stated in all descriptions and promotion texts (website, ...) that the app will go through the device's call log and I guess that if you are looking for an app that will identify numbers you called, you are willing to let it access the call log.
- The app is not storing any data on any servers and is not sharing it with anybody
- I got a Privacy policy set up and a FAQ section on the website that states the above and answers main questions about privacy and permissions. Privacy policy link is provided when in the Play store submission.
- Everything about the app is carefully set up (website, texts, images, logo, custom email, ...) so it communicates that it's meant to solve a problem and the real person is behind it and it's not a scam.
- I filed an appeal to the Policy support team describing all of this.

Also, is there anything I can change to retain the functionality but get published on the play store?

- Is there a better suiting core functionality (then *Device Automation*) that I can declare?
- Is there a way to get call log data without this permission (intent or something)?

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance. Stay safe all.

Comment: Have you tried to explain this in the privacy policy of the app?

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidKhalid 
Of course. I am getting an impression that this is the automated rejection based on the declared core functionality and that it's hasn't been review by a real person.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help if make your app as a dial up app, so the user can directly make calls from your app , like what true caller appdid previously.
But it is always a gamble with policy support team, because most of them are robots!

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely an option. I wanted to keep my app simple with as little permissions as possible, without unnecessary dialogs etc. Right now I am adding a backup feature since that is also in the list of permitted usages and it is useful to have in such an app so we'll see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @mrd good idea, I hope it will work